# Shop by brand/ category list page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm currently setting up a webstore and need to create a page which displays all active sub-categories of my brand category. I would prefer this to be done by static-block as you would be able to click on brands in the navigation menu and it would display all brands. I know I can display this in the layered navigation tab but we have over 900 categories.

It would be worthy mentioning that I'm a total Magento noob and this is the first store I'm setting up using Magento. I've wasted countless hours searching the internet for an answer but most are either outdated or are in the form of a ridiculously expensive extension.

If anyone here can help us out it would be excellent, I know its a big ask.

Also we are using Magento Community Edition 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the some links which will be useful, basically it is called category landing page.

http://www.hannahstothard.co.uk/web/displaying-sub-categories-on-category-landing-page-in-magento/#.VUi8pVf11XI

http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-how-to-add-a-category-landing-page/

Hope this helps
Happy Coding!!!